# Why did humanizing Opal remove her magic?

Tags: artemis-fowl, artemis-fowl-the-opal-deception

At the end of *The Opal Deception*, Opal loses her magic by inserting a pituary gland in herself and turning herself into a human.

> The simple truth was that Opal had been too clever for her own good. By placing a human pituary gland in her own skull, she had effectively humanized herself. Gradually the human growth hormone was overpowering the magic in her system.
>   <sub>*Artemis Fowl: The Opal Deception*, chapter 11: "A Last Good-Bye"</sub>

But we see in *The Lost Colony* that humans *did* have magic, but forgot how to use it.

> He felt the magic ignite in his nerve endings, filling him up, elevating his consciousness to another place. It was a euphoric experience. Artemis realized there were sections of his brain opening up that hadn't been used by humans for millenia. He also realized that humans must have had their own magic once, but had forgotten how to use it.
>   <sub>*Artemis Fowl: The Lost Colony*, chapter 15: "Home Again, Home Again"</sub>

If human brains are capable of retaining magic, especially if they once had their own, why would the human growth hormone overpower the magic in Opal's system?

Answer (score 1):

I see three possibilities, sorry I don't think there is much proper evidence (the origin and content of "the book" are treated as more of a religion than list of facts) so you will have to decide for yourself which fits best.

1. "The Book" has rules against inter-twining species.

This is the simplest answer so going by ocams razor is also the most probable.

2. Humans could use magic until "The Book" was created

This makes a bunch of interesting assumptions about the history of humans/the book. Did humans abuse the power causing significant danger? Was it politics or nature that decided humans were not eligible.

3. It is a writers mistake

How boring :P

If someone knows some extra facts about how the book was made then it may rule out one of the answers, or make the reasoning more precise. However, as of now, the possibilities are quite broad. (and interesting!)

Comment: another possible option - the methods to access magic was different from humans to faeries, or had different rules or limitations, so when the hormones caused her magic to change from one to the other, she no longer knew how to make it work.